# Trying to understand and download file with SFTP.download in Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sftp

I'm trying to download a file into a Rails application using the SFTP method with `sftp.download!('path/to/remote/folder/#{filename}', 'path/to/local/folder)`

The full methods:

```
def missouri 
 sftp = Net::SFTP.start('host.name', '<username>', password: '<password>')
    sftp.dir.entries('/path/to/remote/folder/') do |entry|
        sftp.download!('/path/to/remote/folder/#{entry.name}.txt', '/Users/<me>/local/folder/') 

    end
end
```

I get an error:

```
RuntimeError (open /path/to/remote/folder/filename.txt: no such file (2))
```

If I take away the file extension (txt), I get the error:

```
Errno::EACCES (Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/<me>/local/folder/)
```

When I 'drill' down to that part and run this method, I get a return of the NET::Sftp object with all of it's attributes but no actual download. The SFTP I'm trying to access is an ASPX.human page and the path I'm trying to download the file is within the file structure of the remote site so I'm not sure if I'm trying to access the wrong path?

If I go to the actual SFTP, I can clearly see a file sitting there.

Comment: Can you download the file using any regular SFTP client?

Comment: Have not tried that yet BUT I did just have some success by creating an actual .txt destination file for 'local' and it populated the file with the data! I guess that's the anwer? BTW, I am able to down load the file directly from the ftp site but no, have not tried some ftp client software.

Answer (score 0):

The comment you added after your question makes we wonder about unix rights. Is your script launched by a user that is allowed to write on the destination local directory?

Said differently, what is the output of the following shell command?

```
ls -l /path/to/remote/folder
```

And what are the user/group used your script?

By the way, one thing strange in your code:

```
sftp.download!('/path/to/remote/folder/#{entry.name}.txt'
```

should be:

```
sftp.download!("/path/to/remote/folder/#{entry.name}.txt"
```

Otherwise entry.name would not be replaced.